# Is it wrong using of Swig template engine in node.js?

Tags: node.js, swig-template

Is it wrong to use Swig with node.js in this way? If yes - why?

Please let me know if additional information needed to answer the question.

If it possible, please add links or/and examples of code that can help to understand the answer.

Current code works and makes what I want, but there is feeling that something (or everything:)) wrong here.

Here how my files looks like:

**views/block-header.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

**views/block-footer.html**

```
</body>
</html>
```

**views/layout-home.html**

```
{{HEADER_tpl|safe}}
<h1>Some heading</h1>
<div>Layout home</div>
{{FOOTER_tpl|safe}}
```

**controllers/home.js**

```
var swig  = require('swig');
var layout_home_tpl = swig.compileFile('views/layout-home.html');
var block_header_tpl = swig.compileFile('views/block-header.html');
var block_footer_tpl = swig.compileFile('views/block-footer.html');


var mainPageOutput = layout_home_tpl({
    HEADER_tpl: block_header_tpl(),
    FOOTER_tpl: block_footer_tpl()
});

exports.get = function( request, response ){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(mainPageOutput);
    response.end();
};
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I guess it is ok to use whatever templating engine you like. node doesn't mind.

Comment: My meaning is that using Swing this way is not exactly like explained in Documentation, they using {{title}} for variables not for blocks of HTML. Node.js here is only to explain the using.

Comment: “there is feeling that something (or everything:)) wrong here” — *what* do you think is wrong?

Comment: The true is that my friend said that it is logically not what template used for. In addition I didn't found examples that using swig to include blocks of HTML in my way. For me, this way is more clear and I still didn't found a reason not to use it in this way.

Answer (score 11):

It's not "wrong", but it's definitely not a typical usage. The preferred way would be to use the built-in [template inheritance](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/#inheritance):

**views/home.html**

```
{% extends "layout/basic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Some heading</h1>
<div>Layout home</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views/basic.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**controllers/home.js**

```
var swig  = require('swig');

exports.get = function( request, response ){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(swig.renderFile('views/home.html'));
    response.end();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please say why this way is preferred?